# How to stop one app from ever updating?

Tags: google-play-store

Recently BBC updated their app with the new Material theme, and it completely ruined the app, I reverted back to the previous version using Titanium backup, and I want to ignore BBC app updates indefinitely for now. Much like Windows ignore update etc. Is there a way to do so in the Play Store?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality in Play Store.  However, some backup/restore applications, such as Titanium Backup (that you mentioned) as well as MyBackup support the ability to completely remove or break the Play Store link.